# Android ActionBar wrong home button id

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a `Navigation Drawer`, I can open it by sliding my finger, however, when I click on the home button on my action bar nothing happens. I tried logging the item id in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method and I confirm the id I retrieve is different from `R.id.home`. How do I retrieve the home button's id?

Comment: id is not R.id.home but it is android.R.id.home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id for home is not `R.id.home`, it is `android.R.id.home` because it is a home button created by android itself. using `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` will hopefully works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
           //do something
           return true;
        }else {
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```